# WSDL binding URL changes protocol to HTTP when behind an SSL termination

Tags: soap, wsdl, cxf, jax-ws, embedded-jetty

We have a simple jax-ws SOAP server backed by Apache CXF 3.2.6 in standalone (self-hosted) mode that uses an embedded Jetty. The server was generated wsdl-first using CXF's `wsdl2java`. WSDL is a file on the classpath, and that physical WSDL file has `https://....` in the `location` attribute of the `soapbind:address` element.

When started, the server publishes to `http://0.0.0.0:8080`. The server also sits behind an SSL termination that routes `https://external-name` -> SSL termination -> `http://internal-name:8080`, so externally the service and its WSDL are available at `https://external-name`.

The problem is that when the WSDL is requested from the deployed server through `https://external-name?wsdl`, CXF changes the `location` attribute of the `soapbind:address` element in the resulting file to `http://external-name` (changes the protocol to HTTP from HTTPS and retains everything else ), which causes problems with generating client proxies, Soap UI, etc.

What's worst, our service can't be consumed by our partner's SOA which enforces the usage of published location from WSDL exclusively.

How can we solve this, short of removing SSL termination and having CXF handle SSL on its own? (which is horrible, due to Java keystore maintenance nightmare and having to store the company-wide certificate + private key in the server instance).

Comment: Have you setup/configured the `ForwardedRequestCustomizer` and `SecureRequestCustomizer` to fit this scenario?  Also have you setup the `HttpConfiguration` on the server to indicate what port is secure?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I have (almost) no influence over the embedded Jetty when in self-hosted mode, I can only customize what's exposed here: http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd. I'm not assembling the server or using spring, I'm just using simple `Endpoint.publish` and letting CXF do its thing with the embedded Jetty.

Comment: Per that xsd, your JettyHTTPServerEngineConfigType.connector entries can add the required customizers via the connector specific HttpConfiguration entries.

Comment: I think that that would require far more intimate knowledge than I possess of deep internals of Jetty and CXF. We opted for self-hosted due to its simplicity, but it seems we won't be able to avoid building a full-blown spring app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the desired address as `publishedEndpointUrl` in the configuration. See: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html

Comment: But how do I apply that configuration to an endpoint I create in code `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(address, implementor)`?

Comment: Found it: `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.setPublishedEndpointUrl`. It works, only it needs to be set before calling `publish`, otherwise it has no effect.